# SVG xlink, jQuery on and Safari/Internet Explorer - failing to pass the click event when the SVG is clicked

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, svg, safari, xlink

I seem to have run into a rather perplexing issue with a combination of jQuery `.on()`, SVG `xlink` and Internet Explorer / Safari.

A reduced case example is here: http://codepen.io/mikehdt/pen/MwqORK

The example has two buttons; one uses an svg use, the other embeds the SVG code directly.

The SVG and buttons are like so (note `.icons-svg` is first as Safari seems to get sad if you try to `xlink` something which comes later in the document):

```
<div class="icons-svg"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><symbol viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" id="icon-plus"><title>plus</title><path d="M1600 736v192q0 40-28 68t-68 28h-416v416q0 40-28 68t-68 28h-192q-40 0-68-28t-28-68v-416h-416q-40 0-68-28t-28-68v-192q0-40 28-68t68-28h416v-416q0-40 28-68t68-28h192q40 0 68 28t28 68v416h416q40 0 68 28t28 68z"></path></symbol></svg></div>

<a href="https://www.google.com" class="button">
  <span>Hey, what are you doing?</span>
  <svg class="icon icon-plus"><use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#icon-plus"></use></svg>
</a>

<a href="https://www.google.com" class="button">
  <span>Hey, what are you doing?</span>
  <svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 1792 1792" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M1600 736v192q0 40-28 68t-68 28h-416v416q0 40-28 68t-68 28h-192q-40 0-68-28t-28-68v-416h-416q-40 0-68-28t-28-68v-192q0-40 28-68t68-28h416v-416q0-40 28-68t68-28h192q40 0 68 28t28 68v416h416q40 0 68 28t28 68z"/></svg>
</a>
```

Some ultra-basic CSS just for niceness:

```
.button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;

  background-color: #ccc;
}

.icon {
  width: 100%;
  fill: currentColor;
}

.icons-svg {
  display: none;
}
```

The jQuery is using on, for dynamic binding, like so:

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.button', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        alert('You clicked the button');
    });
});
```

What should happen, and as does in Chrome and Firefox, is that if you click the + in the link with the use SVG, the alert message pops up. However, in IE and Safari it fails to trigger the script which prevents the event and follows the link through.

Clicking the SVG where it is embedded directly works as intended, however for good asset re-use, this is an unfeasible solution.

**Things that do work:**

If you don't use `.on()` and instead use `.click()` then all browsers work, but you lose dynamic binding. If you use `.on()` but don't use `xlink` then all browsers work. It's only the combination of `.on()` and `xlink` which causes this issue to occur.

**Why do this at all?**

When you want to use SVG for icons, keep the resource external (and thus cacheable) and have Ajax events on your site which require dynamic binding.

Has anyone else run into this before? Were you able to get IE and Safari to play nicely with this combo? Might this be a bug in the browser, or jQuery, or a something that Chrome and Firefox are dealing with incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also running into this issue. Even with regular anchors (`<a>`) around the SVG tag, so without Javascript/jQuery.

The solution I've found is to set the following css:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

on the `svg` element.

This way the SVG element will not *capture* the pointer event and it will bubble up, in this case to the anchor, which will trigger your jQuery.

I don't know if you've already found some other fix or workaround?